# Deepface in flask application. Getting error: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I'm basically what I'm running and I'm getting the error:

`'_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'`.

From what I've read I think might need to downgrade either tensorflow/keras, but when I try to run things like `pip install tensorflow==1.14` I get that it's not found. This is all within a flask application and the model is prebuilt outside of the method. Thanks for the help!

```
# Prebuild Model
model = OpenFace.loadModel()

app.route('/verify', methods=['POST'])
def verify():  # Takes in pairs of images to verify
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict(flat = False)
        known = data['known']
        unknown = data['unknown'
        pairs = [[known[i], unknown[i]] for i in range(len(known))]
        results = DeepFace.verify(pairs, model = model)
```

Answer (score 0):

deepface package seems to depend tensorflow 1.9. Could you try to run the following commands respectively?

```
pip install tensorflow==1.9.0
pip install keras==2.2.0
pip install deepface
```